# What is the most effective way to farm TMRs?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I have a few units that I want to aim for Trust Mastery to get useful items or abilities. I tried making a team of these units to repeatedly farm Earth Shrine 1 energy mission (now I'm doing Dalnyra Cavern due to 1/2 NRG promotion), but it takes forever for anyone to level up once.

How do others do this; should I avoid taking a full team, attempt different missions, or something else?

I'm using the international version of Brave Exvius, if that makes a difference - acc. to some comments on the game wiki, outside scripting without modding the game is not against terms for this version but only for JPN release.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the three ways to increase the TMR's level :

1. Fuse a unit into a unit of the same character (TMR level of the fused unit is transferred plus an additonal 5% bonus)
2. Fuse trust moogles into a unit (+1%, 5% or 10% according to moogle rank)
3. Finish a mission (10% chance of getting a 0.1% increase on each unit)

So basically you have to invoke a same unit several time, get moogles through events, or farm the earth shrine, which is the quickest mission of the game. Except if you are a whale (aka a player which spend a LOT of money in this game), you have a limited amount of lapis and tickets for invocations. You also have a limited amount of moogles from events (you should get them... always...), login rewards, trials and so on. So there is only one way to actually farm : the earth shrine.

Now, your options are very limited. You cannot compress the earth shrine quicker, it's a round 50 second mission. What you can do is to optimize the number of days you'll have to wait till getting your first TMR :

- Farm the earth shrine if possible with 5 times the same units. Due to the TMR level of the fused unit being transferred, you need 16% TMR level on 5 units (which is total 80%) to get the TMR (counting the 20% bonus you get from fusing a unit into itself).
- Pray for good RNG

You shall **never** farm the earth shrine with only one unit in your group. This one and only unit **would not** have a better chance for a 0.1% increase.

Another very useful advice is to ask someone to do it for yourself :

- a boy/girl-friend (this is the legal way but you'll pay it one day).
- a child (you may get problems).
- a computer program (this is debatable if this is legal or not, but to my knowledge no ban was ever reported for using Earth Shrine macros on **this** game).

Choose your way.

Comment: RE: Macros. https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/583v0v/i_asked_gumi_about_macroing_and_this_is_their/